# What am I doing wrong for this unit test?

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I am trying to test my reset button on my iOS app. Basically, in the reset method, it resets all the textfields. So I am testing it by assigning record.salesamount.text a string of numbers then executing resetEverything. However, in the NSLog, I am getting (null) for both the before and after logs. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)testResetEverything
{
RecordViewController *record = [[RecordViewController alloc]init];
record.SalesAmounttext.text = @"1234567890123456";
NSLog(@"before %@",record.SalesAmounttext.text);
[record resetEverything];
NSLog(@"after %@",record.SalesAmounttext.text);
XCTAssertEqualObjects(record.SalesAmounttext.text, nil, "Should be a nil");
}
```

Comment: I think `SalesAmounttext` is an IBOutlet. If so it won't work

Comment: @MidhunMP you are correct. So how can I test this without changing the IBOutlet?

Comment: Two options, I don't know whether it work or not:
1) Call `[record view];` right after `RecordViewController *record = [[RecordViewController alloc]init];`

2) call the `loadView` method manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intialize the `record.SalesAmounttext` before use.

```
- (void)testResetEverything
{
RecordViewController *record = [[RecordViewController alloc]init];
record.SalesAmounttext = [[UITextField alloc] init]; //Write this line before use record.SalesAmounttext
record.SalesAmounttext.text = @"1234567890123456";
NSLog(@"before %@",record.SalesAmounttext.text);
[record resetEverything];
NSLog(@"after %@",record.SalesAmounttext.text);
XCTAssertEqualObjects(record.SalesAmounttext.text, nil, "Should be a nil");
}
```

your `record.SalesAmounttext` is automatically initialized  if it is outlet.But in text cases you need to initialize it by yourself as you are not loading it from storyboard/xib.